# Codeigniter: Rewrite to remove index.php not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've just uploaded my website from my local server (XAMPP). It was working locally, but for some reason the rewrite to add index.php to my SEF URL's is not working in my public server. This is what I've got right now:

```
# Avoid listing directory
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# manage language segment 
RewriteRule ^(es|en)/(.*) $2?lang=$1 [L]

# code that allows to get rid of index.php from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

These URL's work:

**www.example.com**

**www.example.com/index.php/aboutme**

while URL's like this generate a **500 error**:

**www.example.com/aboutme**

Here's another combination of condition and rule I tried to solve the index.php removal:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|img|scripts|ckeditor|robots.txt|sitemap.xml) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But it generates a 500 error for any URL without index.php, including the root URL www.example.com

Could you help me fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in your RewriteRule.

Try this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|img|scripts|ckeditor|robots.txt|sitemap.xml) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

It works for us with Code Igniter. The only difference is the slash infront of index.php when compared to your second examples.

Comment: True, but that's from [the user manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html).

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! How come it was working in my local server without that slash?

Comment: Differences in how (or rather, where) PHP runs in your local environment vs your hosted server likely caused the issue. Without more info it is difficult to know for sure.

Comment: @Brendan: my local site is located at c:/xampp/htdocs/mysite (it's not in the document root), and php.ini it's in c:/xampp/php, while in my remote server the web files are in the document root, and I have no idea where php is located since I don't have a dedicated server. Is this matter what makes the difference? In this case, following your advice and always using RewriteBase /, would I solve this problem?

Comment: `RewriteBase /` simply tells the `RewriteRule` where a relative path will be. For example, `RewriteBase /somedir/` would be like saying `RewriteRule /somedir/index.php/$1 [L]` (without using RewriteBase) Also, "/" refers to your document root.